# how to compare peewee dates in python code

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I like to compare DateTimeField with peewee.datetime.datetime.now or today but cannot manage to do it. code snippet is as per below.

```
class subinfo(peewee.Model):
    sub_id = peewee.IntegerField()
    active = peewee.BooleanField()
    sub_type = peewee.IntegerField()
    sub_cat = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = locdb

class subscriber(peewee.Model):
    sub_id = peewee.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    sub_start = peewee.DateTimeField()
    sub_end = peewee.DateTimeField()
    ref_id = peewee.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = locdb

for row in subscriber.select():
    if(row.sub_start >= peewee.datetime.datetime.now):
        sub1, created = subinfo.get_or_create(sub_id=row.sub_id, active=True)
        if(created == False & sub1.active == False):
            q = subinfo.update(active=True).where(sub_id=row.sub_id)
            q.execute()
    else:
        subinfo.get_or_create(sub_id=row.sub_id, active=False)
```

But I keep hitting the following error

```
File "subsync.py", line 51, in <module>
if(row.sub_start >= peewee.datetime.datetime.now):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: try replacing >= to > and its kin

Comment: > hits same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add () to the now
use `peewee.datetime.datetime.now()` !!!